# Printing calling class name in logs using logback

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I have a problem in logging class name of calling class. I have logging utility class written in logback. I created the logger Utility using singleton pattern for some performance reasons. But when I call a logging statement from other class i get to print utility's class name not the calling class.

```
private static LogUtil logutil =null;   
    public static LogUtil getInstance(){        
        if(logutil==null){
            logutil = new LogUtil();
        }
        return logutil;

    }
protected static final Logger LOGGER = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyModule");

public void info(String Message){
        if(LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()){
            LOGGER.info(Message);

        }
}
```

Test class is something like

```
public class LogUtilTest {
public static void testforlogging(){
logutil.info(“Im Logging this message”);
}
}
```

I’m getting output as below printing `LogUtil` instead of `LogUtilTest`, I need help on logging my calling class name

> 2014-04-14 16:47:21 INFO [main] MyModule [LogUtil.info:42] Class Name
>   [com.commonutil.logging.LogUtil] -  Method [testforlogging] - No of
>   Person's data-100001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current callstack using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`. It returns an `StackTraceElement` array. The first item always represents `getStackTrace()`. The second is the method that calls it and the third is the method you want

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName()
```

returns the classname of the class calling the method.